# im getting an error and idk how to fix it: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python

i tried to convert it to an int but still didnt work.

```
with open('port.txt', 'r') as po:
        port = po.read()
SERVER_PORT = port
```

the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/Desktop/chat/client.py", line 20, in 
s.connect((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: You tried `port = int(po.read())`? Did you try `print(po.read())` to confirm you are getting a string that can be converted to an integer?

Comment: try casting it to int ```SERVER_PORT = int(port)```

Answer (score -1):

i found it.

```
f = open('port.txt','r')
port = f.read()
```

Comment: it should do the same, i think it's your indentation, SERVER_PORT should be inside the with, maybe  put it in a function and set it to equal the return value.

Comment: `with` context does not exactly works like local code block. Variable declared within `with` context still persist. PS: How this solved the issue?